# Navigation drawer customization on vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

How to customize vuetify navigation drawer like this image?
[image]

Comment: Since you can not inject additional DIV and style it like the picture - you can try applying some CSS on any of the `:after` pseudo elements and see if it works.

Comment: okay, thanks. I am trying.